# How to convert sql varchar array to Python list?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 for interacting with PostgreSQL database in Python2.7.

psycopg2 saves list in database at first in varchar field, and then I need simply to get the same Python list back.

Insert:

```
data = ['value', 'second value']
with psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONFIG) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (varchar_field) VALUES (%s)", (data)
    connection.commit()
```

In pgAdmin it looks like: {value, second_value}

Then I tried to do something like this:

```
with psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONFIG) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT varchar_field FROM table_name")

    for row in cursor:
        for data_item in row: # here I want to iterate through the saved list (['value', 'second_value']), but it returns string: '{value, second_value}'
            print data_item
```

I have found [possible solution](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.new_array_type), but I have no idea how to implement it in my code.

So, how can I retrieve back Python List from sql ARRAY type?

Comment: What's the type of varchar_field? I hope it is an array, i.e., something like `varchar(4096)[]`. If it is a simple varchar the array conversion won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE pgarray ( x text[] );
INSERT INTO pgarray(x) VALUES (ARRAY['ab','cd','ef']);
```

Then `psycopg2` will take care of array unpacking for you. Observe:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=regress')
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> curs.execute('SELECT x FROM pgarray;')
>>> row = curs.fetchone()
>>> row
(['ab', 'cd', 'ef'],)
>>> row[0][0]
'ab'
>>> print( ', '.join(row[0]))
ab, cd, ef
```

Answer (score 0):

psycopg2 already does that for you. If the PostgreSQL column type is a text array, i.e., text[] you should get a python list of strings. Just try to access the first item returned by the query instead of the whole result tuple:

```
for row in cursor:
    for data_item in row[0]:
    # Note the index '0' ^ here.
        print data_item
```

Comment: It does not work, because it returns string. In this case it will print '{'. I know, that psycopg2 converts from Python to SQL types, but I doubt that it does for SQL -> Python.

Comment: @dimazubrik Your Python & psycopg2 versions?

Comment: @dimazubrik it does! I can see various problems here: you're using a really old psycopg2 version, or your column isn't of the correct type.